# Testing for Randomness in JUnit Framework

Tags: java, junit

I'm working on training myself in a very rigid Test Driven Development JUnit atmosphere. I'm trying to find out what the best method for testing FOR randomness would be in such an atmosphere. For example, I'm working on implementing a randomized queue array that queues and item and immediately switches that item with an item with index 0-(n-1) on the array (thus simulating a random item coming off the queue when it is dequeued). Here's some example code form my enqueue method:

```
        int randIndex = StdRandom.uniform(size); // generate random index to swap with last item
        Item tmp = randArray[randIndex];
        randArray[size] = item;
        randArray[randIndex] = randArray[size]; //perform swap to create a random item for dequeue
        randArray[size] = tmp;
        size++;
```

I want to run a few tests to make sure that my enqueue method is actually randomly switching the queued variable with some other index in the array. Normally I'd just throw some code in the Main() method that iterates through a bunch of enqueue() calls and prints the results, then I'd check to make sure it "felt" random.

But, like I said, I want to do this in a very rigid unit testing framework. It seems like JUnit pretty much exclusively uses assert statements, but I'm not sure what I should assert against what, unless I just run some Monte Carlo type thing and check the average against a certain epsilon, but that seems a little much for testing such a simple method.

Comment: There are some things that are not worth the effort it would take to test. This sounds like one of them.

Comment: .. or there is some hidden agenda ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the test in two parts.

1) You test that by a given sequecne of pseudo random numbers, your queing works as expected. For that define any arbitray fixed number of int values: e.g "5,2,100,3".
Then test with asser that the enque, deque delivers that expected element.

2) Test the `Random()` class of java: You, most likely should  omit that test, because `Random()` is well implemented.

Otherwise for 2) you have it using Chi-Square Random Number Test, and that that that thi sstatistic is within soem epsilon as you stated. But this woul dbe an overkill, so  stay with point 1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are really heading for but I read it like testing the random number generator itself (cause your switching is .. quite straight forward).

If you use java SecureRandom, you should be on a quite good side regarding the entropy, see 
[SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html). If you doubt that, use some entropy checkers or just a sequence of real random from some source in the internet [like here](http://www.random.org/)